# Prevent instantiation of an abstract base class in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class, mypy, base-class, abstract-methods

- I have an abstract base class without abstract methods
- I want to statically check + forbid instantiations of it (with `mypy`)

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from  attrs import frozen

class Abstract(ABC):

    def do_something(self) -> int:
        return 777

    #@abstractmethod
    #def __str__(self) -> str:
    #    ...

@frozen
class Concrete1(Abstract):
    name: str
    some_field: float

@frozen
class Concrete2(Abstract):
    name: int
    some_field: str

a = Abstract()
```

I can achieve what I want by forcing subclasses to implement an arbitrary method (`__str__` here). Is there a better way?

Comment: If there isn't anything natural to expect subclasses to implement, what's the intended purpose of the ABC in the first place?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I thought it may on its own forbid instantiation, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Instantiation *of what*? The base class? But if there isn't anything for the subclasses to implement, what does the interface consist of - what's the point of having a base? The derived classes? Then how are you supposed to use them?

Comment: Yes, prevent instantiation of base class. The subclasses are data classes, whose truthy values are inspected then logged + json-ified. Functions expect arguments whose type is `Abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has no abstract methods, it does not need to be an `ABC`.

Regarding the part about preventing instantiation, just override `__new__()`:

```py
from  attrs import frozen

class Abstract():

    def do_something(self) -> int:
        return 777
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Abstract:
            raise TypeError("{cls.__name__} cannot be instantiated, please use a subclass")
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

@frozen
class Concrete1(Abstract):
    name: str
    some_field: float

@frozen
class Concrete2(Abstract):
    name: int
    some_field: str

a = Abstract() # TypeError: Abstract cannot be instantiated, please use a subclass
```

Yes, this is not static type checking, but it works.